# Jquery table math

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am looking for solution to below issue. I have dynamically created rows in table and they can have similar ids based on part number. I want some simple solution to doing simple math operations with numbers inside table. My table have one Q'ty field which is left for user to fill in, rest should be calculated automatically. Row math and column sums. I am beginner so this is what i came up with.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
   $("[id*='kolicina_']").keyup(function(){
       var a = $("[id*='cena_']").text();
       var b = $("[id*='kolicina_']").val();
       var c = a * b;
       var d = c - b;
      $("[id*='ukupno_']").html(c);
    $("[id*='razlika_']").html(d);    
   });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>Q'ty</td>
        <td>TTL</td>
        <td>Difference</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="cena_1234567">2</td>
        <td ><input type="text" id="kolicina_1234567"/></td>
        <td id="ukupno_1234567"></td>
        <td id="razlika_1234567"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="cena_223421">10</td>
        <td ><input type="text" id="kolicina_223421"/></td>
        <td id="ukupno_223421"></td>
        <td id="razlika_223421"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="cena_556677">200</td>
        <td ><input type="text" id="kolicina_556677"/></td>
        <td id="ukupno_556677"></td>
        <td id="razlika_556677"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>TTL</td>
        <td>TTL</td>
        <td>TTL</td>
        <td>TTL</td>
    </tr>


</table>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need to use `id starts with selector` like `$("[id^='kolicina_']")` which means grab all the DOM elements whose `id` starts with `kolicina_`. Then we search the `tr` object from where the `event` got originated and refer to associated DOM elements like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id^='kolicina_']").keyup(function() {

    var trObj = $(this).closest("tr");

    var a = parseFloat($(trObj).find("[id^='cena_']").text());

    var b = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var c = a * b;
    var d = c - b;
    $(trObj).find("[id^='ukupno_']").html(c);
    $(trObj).find("[id^='razlika_']").html(d);
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Q'ty</td>
    <td>TTL</td>
    <td>Difference</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cena_1234567">2</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="kolicina_1234567" />
    </td>
    <td id="ukupno_1234567"></td>
    <td id="razlika_1234567"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cena_223421">10</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="kolicina_223421" />
    </td>
    <td id="ukupno_223421"></td>
    <td id="razlika_223421"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cena_556677">200</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="kolicina_556677" />
    </td>
    <td id="ukupno_556677"></td>
    <td id="razlika_556677"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TTL</td>
    <td>TTL</td>
    <td>TTL</td>
    <td>TTL</td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: Thank you vijayP. One more thing -  does this code fits if second <tr> have a class attached to it for example <tr class="first_row"> and rest of <tr> are plain without class?

Comment: it will work irrespective of whether class is been attached or not.

Comment: Hmm very strange. My output page is structured similar to this:
In head is script source tag,and head is included from external file header.php. My base.php calls rows from external data.php files on select. in base php there is <table><tr class="first_row"><td>...</td></tr></table> so <td> and <tr> are imported from data.php. - in this case code doesn't work, however when I copy output from console, everything is just fine. Do you have idea what might get wrong? Thank you!

Comment: can you try replacing this : `$(document).on("keyup", "[id^='kolicina_']", function() {`

Comment: OK, I discovered it event should be input than its just fine.

$(document).on("input", "[id^='kolicina_']", function(){
     var trObj = $(this).closest("tr");
     var a = parseFloat($(trObj).find("[id^='cena_']").text());
     var b = parseFloat($(this).val());
     var c = a * b;
     var d = c - b;
     $(trObj).find("[id^='ukupno_']").html(c);
     $(trObj).find("[id^='razlika_']").html(d);
      });

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Note : From your question i think that you want to update the td values only for a single row (means based on the value which you are entering in 2nd column you want to update the calculated values in 3rd and 4th row).

Please check below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
   $("[id*='kolicina_']").keyup(function(){
       var currentRow = $(this).parent().parent();
       var td_cena = currentRow.find('td')[0];
       var a = $(td_cena).text();
       var b = $(this).val();
       var c = a * b;
       var d = c - b;
            var td_ukupno = currentRow.find('td')[2];
      var td_razlika = currentRow.find('td')[3];
      $(td_ukupno).html(c);
      $(td_razlika).html(d);
   });
});
```

Please check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xs9e6moL/30/).

Answer (score 0):

Change the js like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
   $("[id*='kolicina_']").keyup(function(){
        var clickid = $(this).attr('id') ;
        var main = $(this).attr('id').slice(9);
       var a = $('#cena_'+main).text();
       var b = $('#kolicina_'+main).val();
       var c = a * b;
       var d = c - b;
      $('#ukupno_'+main).html(c);
    $('#razlika_'+main).html(d);    
   });
});
```